# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' - 2

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

working as a new person in json i want to show data in tableview cell but when i am populating my table view cell it is giving an exception mentioned above. i had asked this question previously but not get exact solution 
i am getting response like this in view did load

```
-(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    NSLog (@"Count %d", [[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] length] );
    NSMutableArray *inboxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSArray *firstarray=[[[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"messages"];
    for(NSDictionary *tmp in firstarray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
//        [self.inboxmessagesarray addObject:messages];




    }
    [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];







}
```

but when i populate my cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){
        // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
   valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"];
    return cell;
}
```

it is giving an exception . thanx in advance really stuck in it for many days.

Comment: in first array 2o objects are coming . and in inboxmessages array message id is populating but when i populate with tableview cell it is giving an exception.

Comment: no it is 15 u can check my attached project

Comment: may i am doing some stupid mistake thst y i attached my pjct with it..

Comment: Remove your dropbox link from question.

Comment: Upvoting your question, it seems you have less points, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your self.lblArray ***for*** loop into ***inboxmessagesGetSuccess*** method

```
-(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
  NSMutableArray *inboxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSArray *firstarray=[[[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"messages"];
  for(NSDictionary *tmp in firstarray)
  {
    NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
    [self.inboxmessagesarray addObject:messages];
  }

    for (int i=0; i<self.inboxmessagesarray.count; i++)
  {
    [self.lblArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell Number %d",i]];
  }

  [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
    {
        if(response && response[@"messageResponse"])
        {
            NSArray *messageResponseList = response[@"messageResponse"];
            if(messageResponseList && [messageResponseList count]>=1)
            {
                NSLog (@"Count %lu", (unsigned long)[messageResponseList count]);
                NSMutableArray *inboxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                NSDictionary *message = [messageResponseList objectAtIndex:1];
                if(message && message[@"messages"])
                {
                    NSArray *firstarray=[[messageResponseList objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"messages"];
                    for(NSDictionary *tmp in firstarray)
                    {
                        NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
                        [self.inboxmessagesarray addObject:messages];
                    }
                }
            }

        }

         [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of having:

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

```
return self.lblArray.count;
```

}

u should probably have:

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

```
return self.inboxmessagesarray.count;
```

}

As it is now, your tableview tries to populate when app loads before -(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response method gets called, so your inboxmessagesarray is empty at this point, but your datasource is telling uitableview that it should have lblArray.count cells, and that array isn't empty.